# Custom Notification is not displaying in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview, android-remoteview

Hello I am display custom notification in my android application. But issue is that custom notification is not displaying. I saw many threads but did not find any answer related to my issue.

I could not find where is the issue. Can you please look at this.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

// display the notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notificationIcon, Util.notificationBitmap);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notificationTitle, Util.notificationTitle);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notificationContent, notificationMessage);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_logo)
                    .setContentTitle(Util.notificationTitle)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(notificationMessage))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentText(notificationMessage);

mBuilder.setContent(contentView);
// build notification
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify((int)SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

custom_notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notificationIcon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/notificationTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notificationIcon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TGMCians thanks :)

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/15?m=16698842#16698842

> Probably using Support Library, remote views concept does not work in Android 2.X if you are looking for custom notification.

This worked for me and solved my issue.

```
// display the notification
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

// Android 2.x does not support remote view + custom notification concept using 
// support library
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_logo);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(Util.notificationTitle)
            .setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(notificationMessage))
            .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setLights(Color.WHITE, 500, 500)
            .setContentText(notificationMessage);
} else {
    RemoteViews customNotificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notification);

    customNotificationView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notificationIcon, Util.notificationBitmap);
    customNotificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notificationTitle, Util.notificationTitle);
    customNotificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notificationContent, notificationMessage);

    mBuilder.setContent(customNotificationView);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 500, 500);
}
// build notification
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1000, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your layout to use LinearLayout. Had the same problem and that is a nice work around.

Comment: RelativeLayout also works, ConstraintLayout does not work, a very strange behavior.

Comment: Found a related link, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Answer (score 2):

A status bar notification requires all of the following:

```
An icon for the status bar
A title and message, unless you define a custom notification layout
A PendingIntent, to be fired when the notification is selected
from Status Bar Notifications - Creating Notifications
```

You don't specify an icon, which means your notification is not valid.

Comment: I added all (icon, title, message, PendingIntent) and my icon is also valid

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your custom notification is simple design and contains one parent layout- `RelativeLayout/LinearLayout`

**Example layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationIcon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notificationIcon"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="jhyfjhuf"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notificationIcon"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Notification Description" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And set this view in `notification builder`:

```
builder.setCustomContentView(customContentView)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was also the case that the notification did not appear. However, it was strange that if I did not use customView, it appeared without any problem. As soon as I loaded custom view, I immediately found that the notification did not appear.
I also suspected that LinearLayout or RelativeLayout was causing the problem, but in the end it wasn't.

In my case the problem was caused by padding on the root element.

**I finally removed all formatting and settings from the root element, only the width and height remained, and it works!**

If this is intentional, it should be in the documentation. If it was just an accidental behaviour, it was a sad, time consuming thing to do.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

...your content here...

</RelativeLayout>
```